# How to check if a file is empty before being overwritten?

Tags: java, save, overwrite

In my program, I am using a SaveRatestoFile() method to save data from the internet onto a file called Rates.txt. I write the data to a file using a FileWriter.

The problem with this is that if there is any error while saving, the program will overwrite a perfectly good, solid Rates text file and leave a blank one in its place. Is there any way to only overwrite a file if there is no error, and if there is an error while overwriting, to not return a blank text file?

Sorry if this is confusingly worded!

Comment: please paste your code here and explain where do you get errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the data to a new file (such as rates.txt.tmp), then delete the original and move the new one over the original if the save succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

First write to a temporary file, then if that is successful replace the Rates.txt file with the temporary file and then delete the temporary file.